# How to print only last column?

Tags: text-processing, awk

```
echo -e 'one two three\nfour five six\nseven eight nine'
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
```

how can I do some "MAGIC" do get this output?:

```
three
six
nine
```

UPDATE:
I don't need it in this specific way, I need a general solution so that no matter how many columns are in a row, e.g.: awk always displays the last column.

Comment: Lance please research your questions before asking. Searching google for the subject line of your posts shows the answer in the snippents. Searching "awk last column" gives several great answers starting with result 1. Also, [this 5 minute awk primer](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html) is worth reading all the way through so you know what's possible in the future.

Comment: @Caleb The link is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can even be done only with `'bash'`, without `'sed'`, `'awk'` or `'perl'`:

```
echo -e 'one two three\nfour five six\nseven eight nine' |
  while IFS=" " read -r -a line; do
    nb=${#line[@]}
    echo ${line[$((nb - 1))]}
  done
```

Comment: Hmm, or also, assuming your input is actually space-separated: `... | while read -r line; do echo ${line##* }; done`

Comment: @glenn: This was my first idea, but when I read the 'read' manual, I saw this array function which I found useful.  It can also be easily modified to give any field indexed from the right.

Comment: `bash` array index is subject of arithmetic evaluation, so `echo ${line[nb - 1]}` is enough. As speaking about `bash`, you can just skip the “nb” things: `echo ${line[-1]}`. A more portable alternative of the later: `echo ${line[@]: -1]}`. (See [Stephane Chazelas' comment on negative indexes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64672/how-to-cut-select-a-field-from-text-line-counting-from-the-end/64674#comment92771_64674) elsewhere.)

Answer (score 86):

Try:

```
echo -e 'one two three\nfour five six\nseven eight nine' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: I updateted the Q

Comment: please note that awk is limited to 99 fields... :/ This just bite me in the past days ( `ps -ef | awk '{ print $NF }'` had some lines truncated...) Perl doesn't have that limitation. ( http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Limitations-of-Usual-Tools.html : "Traditional Awk has a limit of 99 fields in a record. Since some Awk implementations, like Tru64's, split the input even if you don't refer to any field in the script, to circumvent this problem, set ‘FS’ to an unusual character and use split." )

Comment: @OlivierDulac what `awk` implementations have that limitation? I've never seen it. My `mawk` will choke on `32768` but my `gawk` and `igawk` can deal with millions happily. Even my busybox's `awk` can deal with millions. I've never come across an `awk` that can't deal with 100 fields, that's a tiny number, after all. Are you sure that information is still relevant? Even on Solaris?

Comment: @terdon,  see the links in my comment ^^ (and believe me, some "legacy" system can survive a loooooooog time in some environments.  on some, tar hapilly extract to "/", bash doesn't have some of the usefull builtins (nor $BASH_SOURCE, for example), awk choke on NF>99, etc ... :(  )

Comment: @OlivierDulac fair enough. I just haven't come across it. I hope it's vanishingly rare today since 99 is a tiny number.

Answer (score 25):

It's easier than you think.

```
$ echo one two three | awk '{print $NF}'
three
```

Answer (score 17):

Try `grep` (shorter/simpler, but 3x slower than `awk` because of regex usage):

```
grep -o '\S\+$' <(echo -e '... seven eight nine')
```

Or `ex` (even more slower, but it prints the whole buffer after finish, more useful when it needs to be sorted or edited in-place):

```
ex -s +'%s/^.*\s//g' -c'%p|q!' <(echo -e '... seven eight nine')
ex +'%norm $Bd0' -sc'%p|q!' infile
```

<sup>To change in-place, replace `-sc'%p|q!'` with `-scwq`.</sup>

Or `bash`:

```
while read line; do arr=($line); echo ${arr[-1]}; done < someinput
```

---

#### Performance

Given the generated 1GB file via:

```
$ hexdump -C /dev/urandom | rev | head -c1G | pv > datafile
```

I've performed the parsing time stats (ran ~3x and took the lowest, tested on MBP OS X):

- using `awk`:

  ```
  $ time awk '{print $NF}' datafile > /dev/null
  real    0m12.124s
  user    0m10.704s
  sys 0m0.709s
  ```
- using `grep`:

  ```
  $ time grep -o '\S\+$' datafile > /dev/null
  real    0m36.731s
  user    0m36.244s
  sys 0m0.401s

  $ time grep -o '\S*$' datafile > /dev/null
  real    0m40.865s
  user    0m39.756s
  sys 0m0.415s
  ```
- using `perl`:

  ```
  $ time perl -lane 'print $F[-1]' datafile > /dev/null
  real    0m48.292s
  user    0m47.601s
  sys 0m0.396s
  ```
- using `rev` + `cut`:

  ```
  $ time (rev|cut -d' ' -f1|rev) < datafile > /dev/null
  $ time rev datafile | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev > /dev/null
  real    1m10.342s
  user    1m19.940s
  sys 0m1.263s
  ```
- using `ex`:

  ```
  $ time ex +'%norm $Bd0_' -sc'%p|q!' datafile > /dev/null
  real    3m47.332s
  user    3m42.037s
  sys 0m2.617s
  $ time ex +'%norm $Bd0' -sc'%p|q!' datafile > /dev/null
  real    4m1.527s
  user    3m44.219s
  sys 0m6.164s
  $ time ex +'%s/^.*\s//g' -sc'%p|q!' datafile > /dev/null
  real    4m16.717s
  user    4m5.334s
  sys 0m5.076s
  ```
- using `bash`:

  ```
  $ time while read line; do arr=($line); echo ${arr[-1]}; done < datafile > /dev/null
  real    9m42.807s
  user    8m12.553s
  sys 1m1.955s
  ```

Answer (score 7):

```
... | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]'
```

Comment: Key points: `-a`, autosplit fields into `@F` array; `-l` chops off `$/` (input record separator) and saves it to ``$\`` (output record separator). Because no octal number provided with `-l`, original `$/` is applied in print (line endings); `-n` loop code; `-e` execute code immediately hereafter. See `man perlrun`.

Answer (score 5):

It can also be done using `'sed'`:

```
echo -e 'one two three\nfour five six\nseven eight nine' | sed -e 's/^.* \([^ ]*\)$/\1/'
```

**Update:**

or more simply:

```
echo -e 'one two three\nfour five six\nseven eight nine' | sed -e 's/^.* //'
```

Comment: more simply is better!

Comment: @mdpc: I agree, but as the more complicated solution was already posted, I decided to keep it.

Answer (score 5):

Or using [`cut`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_cut.htm):

```
echo -e 'one two three\nfour five six\nseven eight nine' | cut -f 3 -d' '
```

although this does not satisfy the 'general solution' requirement. Using [`rev`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rev.htm) twice we can solve this as well:

```
echo -e 'one two three\nfour five six\nseven eight nine' | rev | cut -f 1 -d' ' | rev
```

Comment: I do not think 'rev' can be found on all Unix (AIX, Solaris, ...) or is installed on all Linux, but nice alternative solution.

Comment: +1 for double rev, but as a side note, `rev` does not work with 'wide' characters, only single byte ones, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can first check if there is at least one column.

```
echo | awk '{if (NF >= 1) print $NF}'

echo 1 2 3 | awk '{if (NF >= 1) print $NF}'
```

Comment: Or less verbosely `awk 'NF{print $NF}'`.

Answer (score 2):

In perl this can be done as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#create a line of arbitrary data
$line = "1 2 3 4 5";

# splt the line into an array (we call the array 'array', for lolz)
@array = split(' ', $line);

# print the last element in the array, followed by a newline character;
print "$array[-1]\n";
```

output:

```
$ perl last.pl
5
$
```

You could also loop through a file, heres  an example script I wrote to parse a file called budget.dat

example data in budget.dat:

```
Rent              500
Food              250
Car               300
Tax               100
Car Tax           120
Mag Subscription  15
```

(you can see i needed to capture only the "last" column, not column 2 only)

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$budgetfile = "budget.dat";
open($bf, $budgetfile)
        or die "Could not open filename: $filename $!";


print "-" x 50, "\n";
while ( $row = <$bf> ) {
        chomp $row;
        @r = split (' ', $row);
        print "$row ";
        $subtotal += $r[-1];
        print "\t$subtotal\n";
}
print "-" x 50, "\n";
print "\t\t\t Total:\t$subtotal\n\n";
```

Comment: I realised someone else already commented the same, sorry about that, at least I have a few examples too, hopefully it adds to the discussion anyway.