# How to cut (select) a field from text line counting from the end?

Tags: shell, text-processing, cut

I know how to select a field from a line using the cut command. For instance, given the following data:

```
a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j
k,l,m,n,o
```

This command:

```
cut -d, -f2 # returns the second field of the input line
```

Returns:

```
b
g
l
```

My question: How can I select the second field *counting* from the end? In the previous example, the result would be:

```
d
i
n
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4304917/789593

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Reverse the input before and after `cut` with `rev`:

```
<infile rev | cut -d, -f2 | rev
```

Output:

```
d
i
n
```

Comment: I have many small snippets in my bin folder. rcut is for precisely this:
    #!/bin/bash
    rev | cut "$@" | rev

Comment: It's too bad `cut` can't take negative field indices (like Python).

Answer (score 20):

Try doing this with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk -F, '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
```

Or using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -F, -lane 'print $F[-2]' file.txt
```

Or using [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) (thanks manatwork) :

```
ruby -F, -lane 'print $F[-2]' file.txt
```

Or using `bash` (thanks manatwork) :

```
while IFS=, read -ra d; do echo "${d[-2]}"; done < file.txt
```

Or using [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
cat file.txt |
python -c $'import sys\nfor line in sys.stdin:\tprint(line.split(",")[-2])'
```

Comment: `bash` not needs fixed column count for this: `while IFS=, read -ra d; do echo "${d[-2]}"; done < file.txt`.

Comment: BTW, your third solution also works if you change `perl` with `ruby`.

Comment: Thanks, `ruby` added, `bash` edited.

Comment: If the 4th field may start with `-` or (depending on the environment, shell, or how the shell was compiled), may contain backslash characters, then `echo` is not an option. Why do you need to con`cat`enate `file.txt` with _nothing_ before feeding it to `python`!?. You need `read -A` instead of `read -a` in `ksh93` and `zsh`. Negative subscripts work in `zsh` but only in recent versions of `ksh93` and `bash`. In older versions, you can use `${d: -2:1}`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, I think you mean `${d[@]: -2:1}` in your last sentence.

Comment: @manatwork, yes sorry, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I suspected this answer came from someone called Gilles, only it happens to be different from the Gilles I suspected. The same Gilles under a different name perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -E 's/^([^,]*,)*([^,]*)(,[^,]*){1}$/\2/' infile
```

Output:

```
d
i
n
```

#### Explanation

- `([^,]*,)*` matches any number of non-comma charecter followed by a comma, i.e. any number of columns.
- `([^,]*)` matches a column.
- `(,[^,]*){1}` matches one column at the end, if you change the quantifier `{1}` to `{2}` it matches the third column from the end etc.