# Get the last word on each line

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, regular-expression

I have a large text file generated from strace which contains in brief :

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 42.93    3.095527         247     12512           unshare
 19.64    1.416000        2975       476           access
 13.65    0.984000        3046       323           lstat
 12.09    0.871552         389      2239       330 futex
 11.47    0.827229          77     10680           epoll_wait
  0.08    0.005779          66        88           fadvise64
  0.06    0.004253           4      1043       193 read
  0.06    0.004000           3      1529         3 lstat
  0.00    0.000344           0      2254      1761 stat
[...]
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           fallocate
  0.00    0.000000           0        24           access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           open
```

Excluding the first header line, I would like to get from each line the last field, corresponding to the syscall column. Those would include:

- unshare
- access
- lstat
- futex
- epoll_wait
- .
- ..
- ...

This is what I tried
`tail -n -13 seccomp | awk '{print $5}'`, which has been able to ignore the first line but somehow some lines containing the error row are ignored due to my search been not refined.

How do i implement this?

Comment: The reason using `$5` in awk doesn't work is that some of the lines have more fields than the others, namely the error column is empty in most lines, but not all of them. That sort of output is annoying to parse.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622314/108618

Answer (score 13):

Or like so:

```
awk 'NR>2 {print $NF}' seccomp
unshare
access
.
.
.
```

which, for lines beyond the second, prints the last field of the line. `NF` holds the number of fields, `$NF` "expands" to the last field's contents¹.

---

<sup>¹ or the whole record if it doesn't contain any field (is made of blanks only with the default value of `FS`, the field separator).</sup>

Comment: an explanation of the command is much appreciated..

Comment: @geek I'm guessing that the variable `$NF` contains the number of fields, so if there are 6 fields, it prints field 6, and if there are 8 fields, it prints field 8, thus always the last field.  And `NR>2` probably means to only apply this if the line number is larger than two.

Comment: @gerrit, no, `$NF` is the `$` unary operator applied to the contents of the `NF` variable, like `$1` (or `$ 1` or `$ (2/2)`) is the `$` operator applied to the `1` number.

Comment: @gerrit no need to guess since awk has a man page (e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html), plus a POSIX spec (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), plus a manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and various books plus millions of examples online.

Comment: @geek documenting basic features of any well-documented tool/language in every answer posted in a forum is a waste of time and just adds clutter.

Comment: @EdMorton Not when someone is asking a specific question it isn't. It's ridiculous to answer a question and then not explain it. That doesn't help. That doesn't help them learn. It's incomplete. Might as well just tell them to RTFM. That's basically what you're saying.

Comment: @Pryftan it'd be ridiculous to explain every basic construct in every tool/language in every answer. At some point you have to do **some** amount of learning on your own if you want to use a tool/language. This answer contains `NR`, `NF`, and `print` and the most basic single awk `condition { action }` statement possible - I don't think it's outrageous to expect someone to look up what those mean.

Answer (score 10):

You can easily use `grep` with option `-o` (short form of `--only-matching`).

```bash
grep -o "\w*$" filename
```

- `\w` matches any word character (alphanumeric and underscore)
- `\w*` matches multiple (including zero) word characters
- `\w*$` matches multiple word characters at the end of the line

To skip the header, use `tail -n +3` as suggested by others:

```bash
tail -n +3 filename | grep -o "\w*$"
```

The output is like this:

```
unshare
access
lstat
futex
epoll_wait
fadvise64
read
lstat
stat
fallocate
access
open
```

Comment: To have this actually match everything after the last space (not just what `\w` matches), use `grep -o '[^ ]*$'` instead.

Comment: Using `grep -o '[^ ]*$'` matches any character & space including [...] the first field on line 10

Comment: `grep -o "\w*$" filename` - works like a charm, sometimes grep seems to be less overcomplicated than the others `awk and sed`

Answer (score 9):

With `sed` it would be simply

```
sed '1,2d;s/.* //'
```

- `1,2d` mean to `d`elete the first to second line, replacing the `tail`
- the `s`ubstitute command removes everything up to the last whitespace, so you don't need to count columns

To my knowledge, syscalls can't contain any whitespace, so this should work. Otherwise you could rely on the name starting at the 61st character, removing the first 60:

```
sed '1,2d;s/.\{60\}//'
```

Comment: Or `< strace.txt tail -n +3 | cut -c 52-` and `cut` would make it easier to set an ending position, too. (I counted 51 chars before the syscall name, not sure why we got a different number.) If some of lines could be shorter, you might want to use `s/.\{1,60\}//` in sed to clear the short lines too.

Comment: I always appreciate answers using `sed` instead of more complicated tools such as `awk`, `perl`, etc. @ilkkachu using `cut` would only work if that exact number of characters was always in the output, while the original `sed` command above would work regardless of the number of characters before the "last word."

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, yeah, when looking for the last space-separated field, yes. But if we instead wanted one of the middle columns from data formatted like that, e.g. the "errors" column here... Then that would probably be best done by just counting characters. (Or by trying to find if the tool creating the data had an alternate output format...) I meant that as an alternative to the other sed one at the end, the one with the `s/.{60}//`

Comment: The syscalls correspond to C function names, so you're right, they can't contain any whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

The standard idiom for printing the last field on a line is

```
awk '{print $NF}'
```

The `NF` variable is automatically set to the **N**umber of **F**ields on the line, and then `$` extracts that field.

I'd say the easiest and safest way to get rid of the unwanted header lines is with `egrep`.

Putting this all together we have:

```
scs$ awk '{print $NF}' seccomp | egrep -v '^(--*|syscall)$'
```

(This would wrongly exclude an actual syscall named "syscall".  Presumably that shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. `awk '{print $NF}' seccomp | egrep -v '^(--*|syscall)$'` = `awk '$NF !~ /^(--*|syscall)$/{print $NF}'`. By the way, `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `grep` and `tail` with perl-style regex

```
grep -Po '.* \K.*' file | tail -12
unshare
access
lstat
futex
epoll_wait
fadvise64
read
lstat
stat
fallocate
access
open
```

```
grep -o '[^] ]*$' file | tail -12
unshare
access
lstat
futex
epoll_wait
fadvise64
read
lstat
stat
fallocate
access
open
```

Comment: `tail -n+3` would likely be more appropriate here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Indeed, or `tail +3`

Comment: Yes, though `tail -n +3` is the standard version. `tail +3` is the *historical* one but deprecated. The GNU implementation of `tail` takes it as getting the last 10 lines of the file called `+3`  if 200112 <= `$_POSIX2_VERSION` < 200809 as those POSIX versions required.

Comment: Using `tail -12` if am right counts from the last line  rather than first and the number -12 increments down to the top. It has a weird behaviour as `tail -12 seccomp` takes the tenth line and excludes the first i guess it' because it was max of twelve lines

Comment: @geek That is correct hence why Stéphane Chazelas rightly suggested to work from the top in the comments. The solution with tail -12 is also not flexible i.e if your needed output is more than 12 lines after removing the header lines.

Answer (score 2):

If all the important lines begin with a digit, then

```
awk '$1~/^[0-9]/{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.words[*-1].put;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.words.tail.put;'
```

Command line flags `-ne` are used to run the code linewise (non-autoprinting) over the file. The `.words` call breaks on whitespace: it's short for `$_.words` wherein `$_` denotes the 'topic' variable. Indexing is accomplished via `[*-1]` 'whatever-star'-minus-one to get the last word, or more simply with `.tail`. Printing is accomplished using `.put` ('print-using-terminator', aka `\n`).

Sample Input:

```
 42.93    3.095527         247     12512           unshare
 19.64    1.416000        2975       476           access
 13.65    0.984000        3046       323           lstat
 12.09    0.871552         389      2239       330 futex
 11.47    0.827229          77     10680           epoll_wait
  0.08    0.005779          66        88           fadvise64
  0.06    0.004253           4      1043       193 read
  0.06    0.004000           3      1529         3 lstat
  0.00    0.000344           0      2254      1761 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           fallocate
  0.00    0.000000           0        24           access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           open
```

Sample Output:

```
unshare
access
lstat
futex
epoll_wait
fadvise64
read
lstat
stat
fallocate
access
open
```

Note: if having the header line show up in your output is problematic, you can skip outputting the initial 2 lines with the following code: below `++$` acts as an anonymous `state` variable that only initializes once, and then increments to count the lines as they're processed:

```perl
raku -ne '.words.tail.put if ++$ > 2;'
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/state
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

`GNU dc` , an `RPN` desk calculator , can pop space separated arguments from its stack. For string data, as is the last field, we enclose it within square brackets first using `sed` stream editor.

```bash
< file \
sed -En '1,2!s/\S+$/[&]/p' |
dc -e "[q]sq [?z0=qpcz0=?]s?
0_0=?"
```

---

`POSIXly sed` can take care of popping the last field. We replace all spaces by newlines and then keep deleting the leading elements . This process terminates wHen no space remains => we are at the last field. Assuming no trailing spaces.

```bash
sed '1,2d
  y/ /\n/
  /\n/D' file
```

---

`perl` can do it by using the ternary operator ?

```
perl -pe '($_) = $.>2 ? /\S+\n/g : ()' file
```