# Extract file names from a 7-zip archive one-by-one and use the name as a parameter to a java program in a terminal

Tags: shell-script, p7zip

I am trying to write a bash script that will first extract files one-by-one from an archive and call a java program with the file name as a parameter to do something. I have tried with the following script, but it does not work.

I am facing the following problem:

Assuming the compressed file name is `compressed.7z`. Say there are two files inside the compressed.7z archive: `sample_1.json` and `sample_2.json` (could be anything). The `7za` command always outputs `compressed.7z` as file name, which I don't want. I just want to get the extracted `sample_1.json` in the output folder, and give the name to the java command, then `sample_2.json` in the next iteration.

Could anybody can help in this issues?
Thanks in advance.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.7z
do
    7za x -ooutput  "${file}" | java -jar Remove_BoilerPlate_JSON_Updated.jar "${file}";
done
```

Comment: why? can't you normal extract archive only, then just process file names from `7za l` on second run?

Answer (score 1):

This may be not the most efficient way to do this, but here is what you asked.

First, you need the list of files in the archive. You can get it with `7za l`. There is an [undocumented](https://superuser.com/a/1073272/1203531) `-ba` switch which makes the output [easier to process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55355466/14114987). We can [take the last column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17066/423679) of that output, which holds the names of the archived files, with `awk '{print $NF}'`. To get the output of the command as values in your script, we can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) with `$()` syntax.

You can use `e` command instead of `x` in your `7za` file extraction command because you take only files and do not need any directory structure from the archive. Do not forget to provide the archive name as an argument.

Following the above, the script would be something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(7za l -ba compressed.7z | awk '{print $NF}')
do
   7za x -ooutput compressed.7z  "$file"
   java -jar Remove_BoilerPlate_JSON_Updated.jar output/"$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With libarchive's `bsdtar` + GNU `tar`, You could do something like:

```
bsdtar cf - @compressed.7z |
  tar -x --to-program='
    cat > file.json &&
      java -jar Remove_BoilerPlate_JSON_Updated.jar file.json
  '
```

Where `bsdtar` reformats the `7z` file on the fly to `ustar` for GNU `tar` (as GNU `tar` doesn't support the 7z format), and use GNU `tar`'s `--to-program` feature, to pipe each member to a program instead of storing it on disk.

Here, we do store the input always into `file.json` and call `java` on that file. If `java` can take the input directly from its stdin, you can just do `--to-program='java -jar Remove_BoilerPlate_JSON_Updated.jar'` instead. Or possibly `--to-program='java -jar Remove_BoilerPlate_JSON_Updated.jar /dev/stdin'`.

If it's important that `java` receives the file name as stored in the archive, you can get it from the `$TAR_FILENAME` environment variable: `--to-program='f=${TAR_FILENAME##*/}; cat > "$f" && java -jar Remove_BoilerPlate_JSON_Updated.jar "$f" && rm -f -- "$f"'`