# How to use cut to get the last field of /proc/pid/maps?

Tags: cut

I need to do some processing on the list of .so loaded by a process.
I tried cut with space as a delimiter but I didn't succeed. How to correctly pipe the output of cat /proc/PID/maps into cut to get the last field ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print only last column?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/how-to-print-only-last-column)  --- I think all you need to know is how to get a last field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the last field often is a bit tricky. Options are

```
awk '{print $NF}' /proc/PID/maps
```

(note that `awk` returns the last field with an entry, this will return `0` instead of an empty field for inode=0 entries)

or double-reversing a line with selecting the first field in between:

```
rev /proc/PID/maps | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

Use `grep` to match characters except for space, then match till the end of line:

```
grep -o '[^ ]*$' /proc/PID/maps
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on `maps`’ fixed padding:

```
cut -c74- /proc/.../maps
```

(on 64-bit platforms).

Extracting the last field in all cases, *e.g.* with `awk '{ print $NF }'`, is misleading with `maps` since lines can omit the backing file or use (“[heap]” etc.) entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Cut is a bit limited. If you have in file, file: `12345 abcde 12438` you can parse it with `cat file | awk '{print $2}'` to get `abcde` which you can pipe or redirect.